# How to handle infinite recursion of Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, jdbc, spring-data

My problem is I have two classes as follows

```
    public class User implements UserDetails {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private Long Id;
        @OneToOne
        @JsonManagedReference
        private Wallet wallet;
         .........
         // Getters and setters..
    }
```

And

```
@Entity
public class Wallet {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long Id;
@OneToOne()
@JsonBackReference
private User user;
.........
//Getters and setters.
}
```

Sometimes I need the `Wallet` information from the `User` model and at other times I need the reverse.

So, if I write Json Ignore or Json back reference on any of the side I cant get the other object.

**For example :** If I write `@JsonBackReference` in `Wallet` class I cant get the `User` Information while querying the `Wallet`.

My question is how to handle this situation. I have tried both `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonBackReference`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Jackson 2.0+, you may use `@JsonIdentityInfo` to solve your issue.

Here are the [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html) with a complete example.

Comment: Thanks, This one works fine but while converting the inner domain classes to DTO I am having a problem. I am using either 'ModelMapper' or 'ObjectMapper' do you have any Idea of how to convert the Domain classes which contain inner Domain classes to the DTO's which contain inner DTO. Please share it if you have any Idea I really need it, coz I have a lots of fields to convert from Domain to DTO Manually. Thanks in advance